# Custom taxonomy images - output to single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to display images attached to custom taxonomies on the individual product pages. I've used the Custom Taxonomy plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/) and added the images using Advanced Custom Fields. I have 2 custom taxonomies called 'range_logo' and 'features', each with images assigned to them. I need to output the images to the single product page using the hook 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form'.

As you can see below, I have tried outputting a line of text to test if the hook is working correctly, and it is, but the taxonomy image isn't shown when I add the code which is supplied with the Taxonomy Images plugin.

```
add_action( 
"woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form","product_taxonomy_image");
function product_taxonomy_image () {
    echo 'Taxonomy image here';
print apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-queried-term-image', '' );
}
```

Expected results are that the appropriate taxonomy image for the product would be displayed. Instead I got this error:

> Notice: term_taxonomy_id is not a property of the current queried object. This usually happens when the taxonomy-images-queried-term-image-id filter is used in an unsupported template file. This filter has been designed to work in taxonomy archives which are traditionally served by one of the following template files: category.php, tag.php or taxonomy.php. Learn more about template hierarchy. in /var/sites/a/mysite.com/public_html/wpnew/wp-content/plugins/taxonomy-images/legacy/includes/public-filters.php on line 398

I'm using the Avada theme - maybe the layout of the theme's template files could be the reason for the error? I think I may need to use archive.php instead, but I don't have much experience with PHP.

I've tried a few possible solutions and have looked elsewhere for help, but I've hit a wall with getting this to work and I'm not sure what I should be trying next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to the community. First off, I would like to mention that you have written a bit confusing detail about the taxonomy images as you have mentioned using the plugin **Taxonomy Images** as well as **Advanced custom fields**

If you are using the former plugin, you can do something as shown below:

```
add_action("woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form","product_taxonomy_image");
function product_taxonomy_image () {
    print apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-list-the-terms', '', array(
        'before'       => '<div class="my-custom-class-name">',
        'after'        => '</div>',
        'before_image' => '<span>',
        'after_image'  => '</span>',
        'image_size'   => 'detail',
        'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
    ) );
}
```

The above code will give you the images from the category associated with that product. If it is another custom taxonomy that you created, please change the value in taxonomy parameter.

If you are using ACF you will have to get product terms first. Let me know if that's the case and I will share that code with you.

Comment: I do still have an issue. There are 2 taxonomies with images attached. I can only work out how to display one of them. If I have 2 custom taxonomies, for example one is called 'logo' and one is called 'features', how would I display both sets of images?

I have tried:

        'taxonomy'     => 'logo', 'features'

But this is incorrect.

Comment: Are they taxonomies or terms of `product_cat`?

Comment: They're custom taxonomies.

Comment: The `taxonomy` key only accepts a string value so you will have to run `print` twice with the different taxonomy slug each time.

Comment: I wasn't sure of the syntax but I've worked it out. Thank you!

Comment: Great!! More power to you mate.